# removed plymouth made my ubuntu lost

Tags: 13.04, plymouth

I had removed plymouth using

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth
```

This also removed all other packages like ubuntu-desktop., grub., unity., etc..
Now I'm not even getting tty .
Is there any way to get back everything 
or 
Should I need to start again with a fresh copy of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a complete reinstallation.
The other possibility would be to reinstall the lost packages from your Live Ubuntu. With a complete new installation you also get a much cleaner system than before. If you want to upgrade to Saucy, you could also do this now.

Comment: That's what I'm also thinking in my mind!
Already got a copy of saucy ready. :)
Thank You for clearing my mind :)